# Publicar API REST en heroku

Tags: ajax, rest, heroku, slim, swagger

Necesito publicar una `API REST` en [heroku](http://www.heroku.com). He subido la estructura del proyecto al hosting con los comandos `git` necesarios. Además, he creado una base de datos en `heroku` a través de `phpmyadmin`. El archivo `.env` del proyecto contiene la configuración necesaria para conectarse a la base de datos:

```
DATABASE_HOST    = 'hostingmysql329.nominalia.com'
DATABASE_NAME    = 'comparador'
DATABASE_PORT    = 3306
DATABASE_USER    = 'user1'
DATABASE_PASSWD  = 'password'
DATABASE_DRIVER  = 'pdo_mysql'
DATABASE_CHARSET = 'UTF8'
```

La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: STRUCTURE]

En la url: [app](http://pozascompare.herokuapp.com/public) puedo ver la especificación de la `API` que he definido con `swagger` y `slim` pero cuando lanzo peticiones al servidor obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: swagger_error]

Siempre obtengo el error `404` en todas las peticiones. Para actualizar cada cambio que realizo en local utilizo los siguientes comandos:

- `git add .`
- `git commit -am "message"`
- `git push heroku master`

Puede ser que no se estén actualizando los cambios?
Debo escribir la configuración de la base de datos en otro archivo que no sea el `.env`?

Comment: si estás usando slim supongo que tu app corre en php y sólo el front usa swagger leyendo un json? ¿El .env está en el control de versiones? ¿Lo lees usando PHPDotenv o Symfony/DotEnv? ¿El phpmyadmin lo corres en tu local conectado a heroku? Nos puedes mostrar las rutas que declaras con Slim?

Comment: Hmmm aparentemente todas tus rutas estás definidas bajo "public" (ej http://pozascompare.herokuapp.com/public/api/v1/provider). Pero este llamado arroja una MappingException de doctrine. ¿Probaste esto en tu local antes de probarlo en heroku?

Comment: En local no tenía definidas las rutas dentro de public. Si accedía en el navegador a localhost:8000 podia trabajar directamente con swagger sin problema. Me he creado una base de datos dentro del phpmyadmin que hay en la plataforma de heroku. En mi local podia trabajar con localhost:8000/api/v1/provider o con cualquier ruta sin problema.No entiendo a qué te refieres con las rutas que declaro con Slim. Si quieres hablamos por chat mejor porque estoy un poco perdida.

Comment: Si no me equivoco el archivo `.env` no lo toma Heroku, hay una opción para escribir esas variables de entorno dentro de la app. [Aquí te dejo el link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) de como pasar esas variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, primero, ignoro qué librería estás usando para leer tu archivo `.env`, pero suponiendo que es PHPDotenv o Symfony/Dotenv, lo que haces en tu local es exportar el contenido de ese archivo a variables de entorno, y luego acceder a ellas en el ciclo de vida de la aplicación con `getenv` o `$_ENV`.

En Heroku las variables de entorno se manejan en el panel de la aplicación. Las mejores prácticas indican que tu archivo `.env` no debe estar sujeto a control de versiones sino explícitamente ignorado, para evitar que las claves queden en github o donde sea. Probablemente, como dijo [Kleith](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/66539/kleith), Heroku simplemente esté ignorando ese archivo.

Para que el proyecto lea las variables de entorno, anda a tu proyecto de Heroku, a la sección de configuración de tu app (puede ser en https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/pozascompare/settings) y pincha `REVEAL CONFIG VARS`.

Ingresa ahí el contenido de tu `.env` (acá puse dos variables como ejemplo, tú debes ponerlas todas. **Sin comillas**. En un archivo `.env` todo lo que viene después del `=` se asume que es texto así que no las necesitas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso tu app debiera ser capaz de conectarse a la base de datos. Pero queda otro punto. En tu local la definición swagger de los modelos está en la raíz del proyecto y las rutas en `/api/v1/<endpoint>`, mientras que en Heroku están bajo `public`. (Por ejemplo, `/public/api/v1/<endpoint>`).

Para modificar este comportamiento, tienes que **añadir** (o modificar si ya lo tienes) un archivo `Procfile` **a la raíz del proyecto**. Nótese que es Procfile con mayúscula.

El contenido de tu `Procfile`, considerando que estás usando Apache, debiera ser:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Con esos dos pasos:

1. Ingresar las variables de entorno
2. Crear o modificar el Procfile usando `public` como document root

Ya debieras poder usar la app tal como la usas en localhost.

**Paso opcional**

Yo te recomendaría quitar el archivo `.env` del control de versiones  usando  `git rm --cached .env` y luego añadiendo `.env` a tu archivo  `.gitignore`.

Sin embargo, es posible que que en tu aplicación estés llamando en duro al archivo `.env` sin verificar que existe, algo como:

```
$dotenv->load(__DIR__ './../.env');
```

Si lo quitas del control de versiones eso te va a tirar un error. Debieras envolver ese llamado en una comprobación a que el archivo exista:

```
if(is_readable(__DIR__ './../.env')) {
    $dotenv->load(__DIR__ './../.env');
}
```

Comment: De acuerdo, he realizado los pasos que dices y ahora obtengo el siguiente error: https://matchport.herokuapp.com/App.php. PD: no tengas en cuenta el cambio de nombre de la app que ha sido aposta para confirmar que se estaban actualizando los cambios

Comment: revisa los logs de la app en el panel de heroku, en el front no hay cómo ver qué está fallando

Comment: tras revisar los logs, he hecho los cambios necesarios. Fallaba por tema del .env pero eso ya está solucionado. Ahora tengo este error: https://matchport.herokuapp.com/api/v1/origin

Comment: Conseguí solucionarlo. Era debido a unas comillas simples que tenía como valor de  la variable de configuracion `DATABASE_HOST.` El valor de ésta debe ser sin comillas. Un error muy tonto. Gracias!